# How to move a mesh to an exact location

Tags: mesh, vertices, snapping

[image: Hand with separated fingernails]

I have a body model where the fingernails are separated from the hand, and I was wondering on how I would go about on accurately connecting them.

Like, is there a way to snap the fingernails to the vertices on the hand?

Is there a way to accurately move the fingernails into position so that I can join them together?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Welocme to Blender.SE.  Here's a related (if not duplicated) question that may help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36746/how-can-put-a-mesh-into-a-different-position/36787#36787 with the difference that you should define a common triangle to share (e.g three vertices on both object's boundaries)

Comment: There is a vertex snapping feature; in the 3D view footer, there's a magnet - click it and in the dropdown next to it, change the type to 'vertex'.

Comment: Is the finger nail aligned with the finger properly? Or do you have to rotate it as well? Trickier if it is not aligned with the finger.