# Stick a plan on a mesh

Tags: modeling

I am wondering if it's possible to stick the orange plane on the face made by the three columns? I tried with the tutorials showing how to snap objects together. but the plane is never parallel.
Thanks[image]

Comment: Is it really impossible to do? I tried to snap with Face active mode but it doesn't turn the orange plan parallel atthe face of the columns.

Answer (score 5):

### Align rotation in Face snapping

Blender has a tool that is capable of aligning the local axis of an **object** to the target surface normal. You can find that right next to the snap settings:

[image]

[image]

Unluckly, as I said, it works with objects, so it's not available in *edit mode*, and it requires the local axis of the plane object to be already aligned with the plane faces's. So, in your particular case, you should *separate* (<kbd>P</kbd>) the plane mesh and work on the orientation before snapping to the surface (if your plane has a "random" orientation, you can use, for example, the Precise Align add-on, as shown here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36787/15140.)

Comment: nice trick, haven't ever seen an explanation to that button  :)

Answer (score 4):

**Snap to Face** will allow you to project the elements onto other faces, similar to what a shrinkwrap modifier would do when set to axis projection mode. However, if you want to snap **every vertex** onto the target, there is two buttons to enable. Face Snapping (marked on the left), and **project individual**, marked on the right:

[image: face snapping]

Then, a source geometry which looks like this...

[image: source]

...would snap like this:

[image: target]

Comment: Thanks a lot Aliasguru! A little button (project individual) but a big power that makes all the difference. It works perfectly now.